# ASP.NET forms authentication store user token/ticket cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

How long ASP.NET forms authentication store user token/ticket in cache?

Thanks for attention.

Comment: Forms authentication cookies are NOT cached.

Comment: Actually the authentication is an encrypted cookie that contains (and) the expired date/time. So there is cache.

Answer (score 0):

Default is 30  minutes, however you can change it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it equal authentication attribute "timeout" in web.config file?

Comment: @CoDDeR yes it equals to timeout attribute of web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/introduction/forms-authentication-configuration-and-advanced-topics-cs

The default value is 30 minutes, but you can change it.

Answer (score 0):

The default expiration time is 30 minutes. You can change this in the Web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms timeout="60" />
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

This set the expiration time to 60 minutes.